# Handcuffs as protection?

Tags: safety, short-circuit

I am not familiar with electronics at all, but as I was strolling through the stack exchange network I've noticed how it is dangerous to electrocute oneself by touching a wire with one hand and another with the other, which creates an electrical path throught the heart which is very sensitive.

I wonder if this specific danger could be alleviated by wearing (extra long) handcuffs? Which would short circuit the hand-to-hand path?

Comment: Most people who get electrocuted usually know the dangers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this won't work. If your finger end (for example) touches a live part whilst your other hand is firmly earthed, then current penetrates the surface resistance of the finger skin and will flow internally through muscles and internal flesh quite freely (compared to the much higher resistance of the skin surface) hence, the conducting handcuffs won't make a significant difference. In effect the handcuffs are bypassed.

Comment: not to mention all the additional source of danger they pose by getting entangled or touching live voltages.

Comment: I don't understand: wouldn't the handcuffs' conductivity be orders of magnitude greater than tissue, being metal and all?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis the main resistance happens on the skin. So, while live->finger->body->finger->ground has two skin crossings, live->finger->handcuff->finger->ground has four – and hence not less resistance.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Got it1